# Last 3 Months in linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have this line in a stored procedure like this :

```
DATENAME(MONTH, tblReg.StartDate) as [Month],
```

Now I want to convert this line in linq

```
var b = sd.tblReg;

foreach (var c in b)
{
    res += "'" + c.StartDate + "',";
}

res = res.Substring(0, res.Length - 1);
res += "]";
```

and want to get last 3 months.. i.e. current month is Aug so with Aug i want to get last 3 months same if current month is Jan then Dec Nov Oct.. in res like this

```
['May' ,'June','July','Aug']
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @user6628729 - question is very unclear - show your linq and what you want to do but don't know how

Comment: @Kinetic check update please

Comment: @GiladGreen check update

Comment: @user6628729 - So still - you say you are trying to do the sql in a linq query - please show it

Comment: @GiladGreen check update

Comment: This is getting more confusing by the minute.  How are we supposed to know what are the T1 or the TrackDataEntities classes for?

Comment: You should read this about how to ask a question : http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Kinetic sorry i rename this name thats why i write T1 both are same please check now

Comment: What is T1?  Your DataContext?

Comment: yes this is model . where all properties & entities are placed here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this to find previous `3` months using `Linq`. `DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName` will help you to get month name.

```
int month = ..; // given a month
var result = Enumerable
    .Range(-2,18)                  // Compute +/- 3 months for original 12 months.
    .TakeWhile(x=>x <=month)       // Take months until the current month
    .Reverse()                     // Reverse the order as we need backword months.
    .Take(4)                       // Take top 4 months (including current month)
    .Select(x=>CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(x<=0?x+12: x==12? 12 : (x+12)%12))
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3EVT31)

Comment: what is this .. (x>12?(x%13)+1 : x%13));

Comment: Some logic to avoid zero based index value :-)

Comment: when i write -3 instead of -8 this show only 3 months .. June
   ,
   July
   ,
   August where as i also want MAY

Comment: @user6628729 check the update, now it prints 4 back months including current month.

Comment: if i want to do this through for each then how i will do that @Hari Prasad

Comment: Your question was for doing it through Linq, why do you want to do it through foreach? Please note we could achieve this with simple loops, but I would suggest you to explore and do it your own.

Comment: because  i want to display that months in highchart on x axis

Comment: Ohh ... I got what you mean, you want to loop through each value of Linq query right? You could do that just use foreach(var r in result) {}.

Comment: check pastebin please http://pastebin.com/VYecn46S i do that but inside foreach loop when i do this res += "'" + c.mon + "',";  then what suppose to write after c. ???